# Drupal Commerce custom pane as payment and shipping address

Tags: 8, commerce

Currently, Drupal Commerce does not have a solution for "shipping address is the same as payment address" checkbox, which is very unlucky. I was thinking of creating a custom pane with my custom addresses form, where I could easily create such a checkbox. However, I could not find anywhere how to trigger a payment (from commerce payment module) after the addresses form is successfully submitted. Could you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature does not exist in core yet but it is in progress right now. Look for it in Commerce 2.13.